# ros2 autonomous robots in production

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As developers and engineers we learn the most by reading high quality source code.  In the last three years I have been immersed in self-learning of autonomous ground vehicles, and can confidently say that I am familiar with the ROS2 ecosystem.

That includes TF2 and its benefits, the localization package and its use with the Nav2 package, ros2 controls packages, gazebo, and of course DDS and the node lifecycle.  I have also studied SLAM (both traditional SLAM and deep learning augmented), as well as deep learning for object detection, semantic segmentation, lane following, and freespace (drive-able) detection.

Is anyone aware of a good open source project that is based on ros2 and is deployed in a production environment?  The target system would be for a unmanned ground vehicles, however what is more important is the code quality and system design.

One example is the robot bring-up.  I am looking for high quality code that demonstrates system checks upon startup, sensor quality checks and redundancies, etc.

Over the years I have implemented combinations of ros2 packages and deployed them on Gazebo and some basic robot kits from Amazon, with RaberryPi's and Nvidia Jetsons.

I have also learned from many good [educational and research platforms](https://robots.ros.org/tags/#unmanned-ground-vehicle), however I am looking for an open source ros2 project, that is actually deployed in production.

Btw: I also spent time on the [AutowareAuto](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto) project, however there are many inconsistencies in that project (which is a topic for another post)

Edit:

I think this clearpath [husky code](https://github.com/husky/husky_robot/blob/noetic-devel/husky_base/src/husky_base.cpp#L68) maybe close to what I was looking for; albeit not ros2 based

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400319/ros2-autonomous-robots-in-production/) by [sameh4](https://answers.ros.org/users/76665/sameh4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2022-05-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2022-05-10**:
Hello i saw that your want some project which uses ros2 in production level. For this you can use baxtor ros packages. One of the repo is here: https://github.com/CentraleNantesRobotics/baxter_common_ros2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nav2 is used by dozens of companies in production environments.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sameh4](https://answers.ros.org/users/76665/sameh4/) on 2022-05-09**:
Thanks Steve!  I really appreciate the hard work that's gone into Nav2 and the slam-toolbox.   However, this isn't answer to the question. Do you open source any of your robots as Samsung (if you are still there) as a whole project?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-05-09**:
No, we don't and I don't think anyone will. There's not really any benefit to doing so

**Comment by [sameh4](https://answers.ros.org/users/76665/sameh4/) on 2022-05-09**:
I was afraid this would be the answer.  Any suggestions on where to find quality code for the entire robot lifecyle? Including system checks, sensor checks, fall-backs, etc?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about checking out this robot?
https://omorobot.com/en/r1mini/

I developed this robot myself and currently in sales now.
This robot comes with ros2 slam package as well.

https://github.com/omorobot/omo_r1mini-foxy

---

Originally posted by [kyubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40914/kyubot/) with karma: 60 on 2022-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1